# How to change a device from platform type 'MacOS' to 'IOS, tvOS, watchOS' in apple developer

Tags: apple-developer

When adding my device on apple developer I acidentally chose the wrong platform type 'MacOS' when I should have picked 'IOS, tvOS, watchOS'. Now I am unable to remove that device. I can only dissable it and when I try to add it for a second time with the right settings the UDID is now invalid. I assume because it is already been used.

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: Try the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/).